# TSQL Second enmarking based on condition, but also on other endmarking

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Trying to implement some code, where I create two columns that mark the end of a condition. I will start with the code:

```
CREATE TABLE #SampleT (ID INT, SomeVal VARCHAR (10))
INSERT INTO #SampleT VALUES (10, 'X') 
INSERT INTO #SampleT VALUES (20, 'X')
INSERT INTO #SampleT VALUES (30, 'X')
INSERT INTO #SampleT VALUES (40, 'Y')
INSERT INTO #SampleT VALUES (50, 'Y')
INSERT INTO #SampleT VALUES (60, 'Y')
INSERT INTO #SampleT VALUES (70, 'W')
INSERT INTO #SampleT VALUES (80, 'W')
INSERT INTO #SampleT VALUES (90, 'W')
INSERT INTO #SampleT VALUES (100, 'Z')
INSERT INTO #SampleT VALUES (110, 'Z')
INSERT INTO #SampleT VALUES (120, 'Z')

WITH CTE AS 

(
    SELECT ID, 
         SomeVal,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SomeVal) AS RowNumb
    FROM #SampleT AS S
)

SELECT C.*, 
      CASE WHEN C.SomeVal <> C2.SomeVal THEN '**' ELSE '' END AS EndMarking,
      (C.RowNumb / 11) + 1 AS SecondEndMarking
FROM CTE AS C
LEFT JOIN CTE AS C2 ON C.RowNumb = C2.RowNumb - 1
ORDER BY C.RowNumb

DROP TABLE #SampleT
```

Basically, this code works fine. But I want the second end marking to start at the previous end marking of the column Endmarking. In this example I would like that the column SecondEndMarking changes from 1 to 2 at row 9, because that's when the previous Enmarking is filled with **.

Desired result:

```
ID  SomeVal RowNumb EndMarking  SecondEndMarking
70  W   1       1
80  W   2       1
90  W   3   **  1
10  X   4       1
20  X   5       1
30  X   6   **  1
40  Y   7       1
50  Y   8       1
60  Y   9   **  2
100 Z   10      2
110 Z   11      2
120 Z   12      2
```

This might sound a little vague, but with the sample code and the desired output as stated, I hope someone could help me out!

Thanks.

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: @D-Shih Added in question.

Comment: add a ";" before WITH - otherwise, it cannot be run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can try this.

due to `sql-server 2008` didn't support `LEAD` function you can try to use a subquery to reach LEAD function effect

```
CREATE TABLE SampleT (ID INT, SomeVal VARCHAR (10))
INSERT INTO SampleT VALUES (10, 'X') 
INSERT INTO SampleT VALUES (20, 'X')
INSERT INTO SampleT VALUES (30, 'X')
INSERT INTO SampleT VALUES (40, 'Y')
INSERT INTO SampleT VALUES (50, 'Y')
INSERT INTO SampleT VALUES (60, 'Y')
INSERT INTO SampleT VALUES (70, 'W')
INSERT INTO SampleT VALUES (80, 'W')
INSERT INTO SampleT VALUES (90, 'W')
INSERT INTO SampleT VALUES (100, 'Z')
INSERT INTO SampleT VALUES (110, 'Z')
INSERT INTO SampleT VALUES (120, 'Z')
```

**Query 1**:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT ID, 
         SomeVal,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SomeVal) AS RowNumb
    FROM SampleT t1
)
SELECT *,(CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN EndMarking ='**' THEN RowNumb END) OVER (ORDER BY RowNumb DESC) > RowNumb THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) SecondEndMarking
FROM (
  SELECT *,CASE WHEN ( SELECT top 1 SomeVal 
      FROM cte tt
      WHERE tt.RowNumb > t1.RowNumb
      ORDER BY SomeVal )  <> SomeVal  THEN '**'
  ELSE '' END EndMarking  
  FROM CTE t1
) t1
order by RowNumb
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b6b6e/22/0)**:

```
|  ID | SomeVal | RowNumb | EndMarking | SecondEndMarking |
|-----|---------|---------|------------|------------------|
|  70 |       W |       1 |            |                1 |
|  80 |       W |       2 |            |                1 |
|  90 |       W |       3 |         ** |                1 |
|  10 |       X |       4 |            |                1 |
|  20 |       X |       5 |            |                1 |
|  30 |       X |       6 |         ** |                1 |
|  40 |       Y |       7 |            |                1 |
|  50 |       Y |       8 |            |                1 |
|  60 |       Y |       9 |         ** |                2 |
| 100 |       Z |      10 |            |                2 |
| 110 |       Z |      11 |            |                2 |
| 120 |       Z |      12 |            |                2 |
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I am using 2008, so I can not use lead or lag.

Comment: @www.StudioSQL.nl I edit my answer, you can write subquery reach `LEAD` function effect

Comment: thanks, I think the line with the over clause is also causing issues on 2008. (the case when statement).

Comment: I will certainly test your improved answer!

Comment: No, unfortunately, same issue: Msg 11305, Level 15, State 10, Line 90
The Parallel Data Warehouse (PDW) features are not enabled.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b6b6e/28 I rewrite the `CASE WHEN` with `MAX` to subquery you can try it

Comment: @www.StudioSQL.nl No problem glad to help